# python setup version for --pre

Tags: python, version

I use setuptools to build my pkg.

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html

There is a function judge version sequence.

But I want to know what kind of version name can be install

by pip install **--pre**

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version
parse_version("1.9.a.dev") == parse_version("1.9a0dev")
>>>True
parse_version("2.1-rc2") < parse_version("2.1")
>>>True
parse_version("0.6a9dev-r41475") < parse_version("0.6a9")
>>>True
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it immediately...

pep-440 provide regex to check version itssely.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/